# How to calculate the coordinates of missing point in triangle given two points and two sides and one angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have this issue and I've been trying to solve this for hours but wasn't able to find a solution which works in all circumstances. I feel sad because this seems like a simple trigonometry problem. I hope you can help me find a solution to this.

What I try to calculate are essentially the red points (I'll call them `P` later on) at the end of the red lines in this picture:
[image: goal]
The red lines are just for reference and everything is drawn by hand and might therefor not be to scale.

I have a list of coordinates (black points) building a route (black line), for example:
`[ (12, 9), (13,10), (13,11) ]`

In order to find the red points I iterate through the route and look at 3 consecutive points at a time. Where the two edges connect (i.e. the middle point) is a place where the red line starts.

The rules are as follows:

- given are 3 points: `A` for after, `B` for before, `C` for current (shorthand for each triangle and their meaning in the route)
- given is `j`, the length of the red line
- the angle for BCP and ACP must be the same
- if multiple answers are possible, choose the one which 'goes with the flow' and is further away from the corner points for it to form a "Y" shape as indicated by the red line
- calculate the coordinates for each `P` as `(y,x)`

To illustrate the issue I made following diagram of just one such iteration:
[image: sample]
(The y-axis on the grid is reversed in this one, but never mind)

What I already managed to do:

1. Given the points A,B and C, I can calculate the length of the edges as well as the angle `ACB=135°`. For this I used this function:

```python
def angle_between(previous, current, next):
    a = math.sqrt((next[0]-previous[0])**2 + (next[1]-previous[1])**2)
    b = math.sqrt((current[0]-previous[0])**2 + (current[1]-previous[1])**2)
    c = math.sqrt((current[0]-next[0])**2 + (current[1]-next[1])**2)
    angle_alpha = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c))
    return round(math.degrees(angle_alpha), 2)
```

2. I then can calculate `PCB=180-(ACB/2)=112.5°`.

So I know everything I should need to know except the resulting coordinates of P.
I tried to calculate them with the following code but I didn't get the results I expected:
`P = (C[0] + j*math.cos(PCB_rad) , C[1] + j*math.sin(PCB_rad))`

Can someone please help me? Maths is not my strength it seems.. Thx!

Comment: This is not a Mathematica question.

Comment: @yarchik ah I must've mistaken mathematica and math, sorry. Or is there an even better one?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

- Here we post the explicit formula which can be used to another lanugage.
- According to the Angle bisector theorem，
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem
- we can calculate the point `d`  on the `ab` edge and set `dir=c-d` as the direction vector from `c` to `p`

```
Clear[a,b,c,d,ca,cb,dir];
a = {xa, ya};
b = {xb, yb};
c = {xc, yc};
ca = Sqrt[(xc - xa)^2 + (yc - ya)^2];
cb = Sqrt[(xc - xb)^2 + (yc - yb)^2];
d =  cb/(ca + cb) *a  + ca/(ca + cb) *b;
dir = c - d;
```

> `{xc - (xb *Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2])/( Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2] +  Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2]) - ( xa* Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2])/( Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2] +  Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2]),  yc - (yb *Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2])/( Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2] +  Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2]) - ( ya* Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2])/( Sqrt[(-xa + xc)^2 + (-ya + yc)^2] +  Sqrt[(-xb + xc)^2 + (-yb + yc)^2])}`

- Now,`p=c+length*Normalize[dir]`, it can be illustrated as below.

```
rules = Flatten[
   Thread /@ {{xa, ya} -> {1.2, 2}, {xb, yb} -> {3, 1}, {xc, 
       yc} -> {2.1, 1}}];
rules = Flatten[
   Thread /@ {{xa, ya} -> RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2], {xb, yb} -> 
      RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2], {xc, yc} -> RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2]}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
   Triangle[{a, c, b}], {Line[{c, d}]}, 
   Line[{c, c + .5*Normalize[dir]}], Text["a", a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text["b", b, {-1, -1}], Text["c", c, {-.5, 1}], 
   Text["d", d, {-2, -1}], 
   Text["p", c + .5*Normalize[dir], {1, 1}]}] /. rules
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Clear[a,b,c,line,dir];
c = {2.1, 1};
a = {1.2, 2};
b = {3, 1};
line = AngleBisector[c -> {a, b}, "Interior"];
dir = line[[2]];
λ = 0.5;
Graphics[{Triangle[{a, b, c}], Red, Line[{c, c - λ*dir}]}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[λ, bisector, pts];
λ = .5;
bisector[a_, c_, b_] := Module[{line, dir},
   line = AngleBisector[c -> {a, b}, "Interior"];
   dir = line[[2]];
   Line[{c, c - λ*Normalize@dir}]];
pts = {{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 4}, {10, 3}, {11, 2}, {8, -2}, {7, 
    0}, {4, -2}};
Graphics[{Line[Partition[pts, 2, 1]], Red, 
  bisector @@@ Partition[pts, 3, 1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for! .. But I'm so sorry, I've just been made aware by the comment from @yarchik that I posted this in the wrong forum. You obviously made a great contribution and I don't want to just delete my question and repost it in Math, even though I can't use it in this form. Is there a way I can convert this code into Python code or mathematical formulas for me to copy over? :s

Comment: @товіаѕ  I have post another  ideas  to calculate the `dir` from `c` to `p`, and also post the formula which only depend on the coordinate of the three points `a,c,b`.

Comment: Your efforts are really really appreciated! Sadly I can't get it work. Can you maybe take a look at this? I prepared this for you https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17j2CruF2SHE_l-MVnnKpvI7bv2niUVNx?usp=sharing

Comment: @товіаѕ  I don't know Python, it seems that Python can't directly recognize  `d = cb/(ca + cb) *a  + ca/(ca + cb) *b` as a point in 2D.

Comment: :/ Thanks for trying though! .. btw it should be able to do that, the result I get when executing exactly that is `(1.73925645, 1.40082616)`. Is this wrong?

Comment: @товіаѕ  The point of `d`  should be `{2.27851, 1.40083}` and the `dir` should be `{-0.178513, -0.400826}`.

Comment: @товіаѕ as you mentioned in a comment this is the answer you were looking for. Please consider accepting it as well. I will add a proper welcome under the question :-) As always, very impressive answer cvgmt! Kudos

Comment: @товіаѕ  Your Python code should be `angle_bisector(a, c, b, length)` instead of `angle_bisector(a, b, c, length)` since  we calculate the angle `a->c->b`

Comment: okay I managed to do it now. Not sure what the issue was with the other code. Anyhow, happy that it works now - thanks everyone!

Comment: @cvgmt I just missed your comment,  and actually yes I think you might be right that that is the thing that I changed.. -.- What a shame that such a minor mistake caused this much unnecessary effort. Sorry for my mistake!

Comment: @товіаѕ I test the Python code again, and I found that we need to add an option to prohibit matplotlib from stretching graphics, that is, the current graphics are not one-to-one.